# Remove reference from realm object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, realm

I am new in Realm. Following, I am struggling with reference in Realm.

I read data from Realm Database using JavaScript and receive an error: "Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction" whenever I want to change something.

I know the error appear because the object is still linking with Realm DB and we have to open a transaction to modify it.

Is there anyway to get rid of reference in Realm? I just want to get the object only.

### Note:

I search around and find out there is a way to do it using:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object));
```

However, it will change all the variable with type `Date` inside the object and we have to re-format it later, which cause a lot of effort.

Answer (score 0):

What you might look for is the method `Realm.copyFromRealm(RealmObject)`.

In the documentation it is stated as follows:

> copyFromRealm:
>
> `public <E extends RealmModel> E copyFromRealm(E realmObject)`
>
> Makes an unmanaged in-memory copy of an already persisted RealmObject. This is a deep copy that will copy all referenced objects.

But bear in mind, that changes to this unmanaged copy of the managed RealmObject will not update the RealmObject. To bring all your changes back into the RealmObject you have to explicitly do this via a RealmTransaction, where you can update the RealmObject.

Furthermore you may check with `RealmObject.isManaged()` if your chosen object is currently managed by Realm. If not, you don't need to create an unmanaged copy.